# "after receiving confirmation" vs "after receiving THE confirmation"

Tags: articles

I have a pretty easy question, but it really bothers me. Today I saw a piece of code containing the following comment line - "failed after receiving **the** confirmation". I'm not a native speaker, but the article  here seems to be unnecessary. I suppose the phrase would sound "smoother" without it. However, in terms of grammar I think we should use the article. What do you think?

Comment: I believe that it would depend on the context. I reckon using 'confirmation' without the article would sound more natural in most cases. However, it must be noted that if it refers to a specific 'confirmation' that has already been mentioned then I guess it would be acceptable. Just my two cents, as I am no grammar expert.

Comment: I wouldn't bring academic canons of syntax to comments in code, which are typically abbreviated notes, similar to improvised speech in omitting whatever the writer expects to be understood.

Comment: @user178049 I can't imagine "failed after receiving the confirmation" acting as a command -- it looks like a comment to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article would be used when a specific *confirmation* was being referred to, rather than a generic one, if the procedure initiates some action and expects to receive a confirmation from the server that the action had been completed, according to some documentation, for example.  If API documentation specifies that a confirmation will be returned, then we can easily use "the" confirmation to refer to the expected confirmation, the one documented in the API docs. Or it could simply be *the confirmation which the server sends back*.  That idea can be in the mind of the author/speaker; it doesn't have to be expressly stated or already mentioned, especially if the speaker/author believes the listener/reader will know what is being referred to.